# Is there any method to create UML using LaTeX without giving (x,y) co-ordinate?

Tags: pgf-umlcd

I use `pgf-umlcd` package for making UML class diagram. This package generates gorgeous style. But, problem is when new class, operation, attribute is added to the UML then I have to change the (x,y) co-ordinate for each class for better decoration and fitting with the page size. That is more time consuming task.

[image: UML]

If I could set the `l`'s, it is easier to maintain the decoration.

Is there any recommendation/technique/(or any package) to do this with giving less time/effort? Why this package doesn't set the diagram by default?

Comment: It doesn't to the layout automatically because the author has chosen not to try to implement any such feature (which does sound like a much harder thing to do than what it actually does). It's possible to place classes relative to each other (so you could place one e.g. 5mm right of another), would that be useful?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, it is useful, give a demo, please.

Comment: If there is any script that do this for many class diagram it would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR -- see code example at the bottom.

---

It is possible to place a `class` (or similar) relative to another `class`. When you do

```
\begin{class}{foo}{x,y}
\end{class}
```

you essentially end up with a `\node [..] (foo) at (x,y) {...};`, i.e. a node named `foo` placed at the specified coordinate. However, as node anchors can be used as coordinates, you can do something like this later:

```
\begin{class}[yshift=-5mm]{bar}{foo.south}
\end{class}
```

Instead of explicit coordinates, you place it at one of `foo`s anchors, and then shift it a little bit away.

There is just one problem: the `class` node always has `anchor=north`, meaning that it's always the top, middle point that is placed at the specified coordinate.

The optional argument to the `class`, i.e. `yshift=-5mm` in the example above, is added to a style called `this umlcd style`. While you can specify an anchor in that style, it will not work, because the package does

```
\node [this umlcd style, anchor=north] (<name>) at (x,y) {...};
```

Hence, any anchor setting you do will always be overridden by the `anchor=north`. So to make this more usable, the `class` environment has to be modified so that you get

```
\node [anchor=north,this umlcd style] (<name>) at (x,y) {...};
```

instead. That way, while the `north` anchor is still the default, you can now do things like

```
\begin{class}[anchor=west,xshift=5mm]{baz}{bar.east}
\end{class}
```

Here the `west` anchor of the `baz` class is placed at the `east` anchor of `bar`, and then the class is shifted 5mm right.

There are of course multiple anchors to choose from. The `class` is a multipart node, so it has the anchors listed in chapter 67.6 of the TikZ manual. Here is an image pointing to them:

[image: anchors on class node]

(The code generating this image is given at the bottom.)

You can of course use both `xshift` and `yshift` at the same time, or use `shift={( <x-shift>, <y-shift> )}`.

For example, it follows naturally that to place one class below right of another, you would do something like `\begin{class}[anchor=north west,xshift=5mm,yshift=-3mm]{baz}{bar.south east}`.

## Complete example

Complete example with redefinition of `class`. Similar redefinitions of `interface`, `abstractclass`, and `object` can be made. I didn't add them, but can do so if you like.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
% redefine enviroment
\renewenvironment{class}[3][]%
{
\begin{classAndInterfaceCommon}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}%
{\calcuateNumberOfParts{}
% the only change is in the following line, where "anchor=north" was moved before "this umlcd style"
\node[anchor=north,this umlcd style] (\umlcdClassName) at (\umlcdClassPos)
    {\textbf{\umlcdClassName}
\insertAttributesAndOperations{}
};

\end{classAndInterfaceCommon}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{class}{foo}{0,0}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[yshift=-5mm]{bar}{foo.south}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[anchor=west,xshift=5mm]{baz}{bar.east}
\end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Addendum

Here is the code generating the image showing the anchors:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{class}{foo}{0,0}
\attribute{}\attribute{}\attribute{}\attribute{}\attribute{}\attribute{}\attribute{}

\operation{}\operation{}\operation{}\operation{}\operation{}\operation{}\operation{}\operation{}\operation{}
\end{class}
\foreach \anc/\ang in
 {north/90,south/270,west/180,east/0,north west/135,north east/45,
  south west/225,south east/315,
  text west/180,text east/0,text split west/200,text split east/340,
  two west/180,two east/0,two split west/140,two split east/40,
  three west/180,three east/0,three split west/220,three split east/320
}
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,pin={[pin distance=1cm,pin edge={solid,latex-,black}]\ang:\texttt{\anc}}] at (foo.\anc) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, you save my time. Would you explain how to make distance of `baz.west <----> bar.east=5mm(x)` and `baz.north<--->bar.south=3mm(y)`?

Comment: @alhelal Do you mean `\begin{class}[anchor=north west,xshift=5mm,yshift=-3mm]{baz}{bar.south east}`?

Comment: yes. you can add this in answer also.