# How to make co-ordinate independent ornamented document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, pgfornament

I have this code -

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Akaash,banglattfont=Akaash]{latexbangla}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz
\begin{document}  
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}   

\begin{center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={inner sep=0}]
   \draw [Blue] (-5,-5) rectangle +(10,10);
   \node [anchor=north west] at (-3,5) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{71}};
   \node [anchor=south west] at (-3,-5) {\pgfornament[width=6cm,,symmetry=h]{71}};
   \node [anchor=north west] at (-5,5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
   \node [anchor=north east] at (5,5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=v]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south west] at (-5,-5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=h]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south east] at (5,-5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=c]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south west,rotate=-90] at (-5,3) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
   \node [anchor=south west,rotate=90] at (5,-3) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
   \node [Maroon,font=\Huge\bfseries] at (0,0) {কিছু};
   \node [anchor=south] at (0,0.5) {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{69}};
   \node [anchor=north] at (0,-0.5) {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{69}};
%   \node [anchor=north east,rotate=-30] at (-1,2.5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{57}};
%   \node [anchor=north west,rotate=30] at (1,2.5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{57}};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
```

The result is
[image]

I want to change my documents so that when I add more text middle of the document(কিছু) the ornaments automatically shifted outer to free the space for the text.

**Edit**

See the following code and output -

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Akaash,banglattfont=Akaash]{latexbangla}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz
\begin{document}  
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}   

\begin{center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={inner sep=0}]
   \draw [Blue] (-5,-5) rectangle +(10,10);
   \node [anchor=north west] at (-3,5) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{71}};
   \node [anchor=south west] at (-3,-5) {\pgfornament[width=6cm,,symmetry=h]{71}};
   \node [anchor=north west] at (-5,5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
   \node [anchor=north east] at (5,5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=v]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south west] at (-5,-5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=h]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south east] at (5,-5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=c]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south west,rotate=-90] at (-5,3) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
   \node [anchor=south west,rotate=90] at (5,-3) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
   \node [Maroon,font=\huge] at (0,0) {
   শিশুকে \begin{tabular}{ll}
   &ভুল শেখাবেন না&সঠিক শেখাবেন।\\
   &লোভ দেখাবেন না &পুরস্কার দেবেন \\
   &নিরুৎসাহিত করেবন না&উৎসাহিত করেবন\\
   &বকুনি দেবেন না&উপেদশ দেবেন \\
  &বেয়াদব বলেবন না&আদব শেখাবেন \\
   &নিঃসঙ্গ  রাখবেন না&সৎসঙ্গ দেবেন \\
&ভয় দেখাবেন না&সাহস দেবেন \\
&লজ্জা দেবেন না& শিখিয়ে দেবেন \\
&ধমক দেবেন না&বুঝতে দেবেন \\
&মিথ্যা বলবেন না&সত্য বলবেন \\
&বেত্রাঘাত করবেন না &স্নেহ করবেন \\
&নিন্দা করেবন না&ভালবাসবেন \\
&অবেহলা করবেন না&গুরুত্ব দেবেন 
&মাওলানা মুরশিদুল আলম , মুহতামিম\\ 
&জামিয়া আরাবিয়া হাজী ইউনুছ (কওমী মাদ্রাসা)\\
    \end{tabular}
    };

   \node [anchor=south] at (0,0.5) {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{69}};
   \node [anchor=north] at (0,-0.5) {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{69}};
%   \node [anchor=north east,rotate=-30] at (-1,2.5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{57}};
%   \node [anchor=north west,rotate=30] at (1,2.5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{57}};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT2**

In my MWE I use the Bengali text because I make a Bangla documents with ornaments. But, you can use English. And, keep in mind that your solution should works for Bengali also.

May be helpful to answer this question [Is there any method to create UML using LaTeX without giving (x,y) co-ordinate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396431/is-there-any-method-to-create-uml-using-latex-without-giving-x-y-co-ordinate)

Comment: Is the Bangla part relevant?

Comment: @Johannes_B no. You can use English also, but keep in mind that your solution also works for Bangla.

Comment: Please edit the question then.

Comment: @Johannes_B I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll note that you had some errors in that table code, you defined only two columns, but you used three (the `&` separate columns, so two `&` give three columns). There also seemed to be a `\\` missing, and possibly a `,` in one of the lines should be `&`. I fixed it so that it works, but because I can't read the language, and don't know what it's supposed to look like, I may have messed it up. But you need to fix that yourself.

---

I would place the text node *first*, and then place all the ornaments relative to it. I loaded the `positioning` TikZ-library to help with this. If you have a node named `foo`, you can place another node next to it with e.g. `\node [left=of foo] ..` See section 17.5.3 *Advanced placement options* in the TikZ manual (for version 3.0.1a) for a description of the library.

One thing to note about the anchors of rotated nodes: The anchors also rotate. Hence, for the node containing the ornament on the right side, which has `rotate=90`, the `north` anchor is on the *left* side of the node, not the top.

If you're not familiar with the `-|` syntax used to position the ornaments in the corner, have a look at [TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429)

I also show two different examples. The only difference between the two is that in the second one I calculate the width and height of the central text node, and set the widths of the ornaments relative to these. That is the reason for the different outputs:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Akaash,banglattfont=Akaash]{latexbangla}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz

\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}   

\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning, % for left=of, above=of etc.
  calc % for let syntax used in second example
}

\begin{document}  

\begin{center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=5mm
]
   \node [Maroon] (text) {
   \begin{tabular}{ll}
     শিশুকে \\
     ভুল শেখাবেন না&সঠিক শেখাবেন।\\
     লোভ দেখাবেন না &পুরস্কার দেবেন \\
     নিরুৎসাহিত করেবন না&উৎসাহিত করেবন\\
     বকুনি দেবেন না&উপেদশ দেবেন \\
     বেয়াদব বলেবন না&আদব শেখাবেন \\
     নিঃসঙ্গ  রাখবেন না&সৎসঙ্গ দেবেন \\
     ভয় দেখাবেন না&সাহস দেবেন \\
     লজ্জা দেবেন না& শিখিয়ে দেবেন \\
     ধমক দেবেন না&বুঝতে দেবেন \\
     মিথ্যা বলবেন না&সত্য বলবেন \\
     বেত্রাঘাত করবেন না &স্নেহ করবেন \\
     নিন্দা করেবন না&ভালবাসবেন \\
     অবেহলা করবেন না&গুরুত্ব দেবেন \\
     মাওলানা মুরশিদুল আলম & মুহতামিম\\ 
     জামিয়া আরাবিয়া হাজী ইউনুছ (কওমী মাদ্রাসা)
    \end{tabular}
    };

  \node [anchor=north] (below) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{69}};
  \node [anchor=south] (above) at (text.north) {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{69}};

   \node [rotate=-90, left=of text, anchor=north] (left)  {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
   \node [rotate=90, right=of text, anchor=north] (right) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};

   \node [above=of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{71}};
   \node [below=of below] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=6cm,symmetry=h]{71}};

   \node [anchor=north west] at (top.north -| left.south)  {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
   \node [anchor=north east] at (top.north -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south west] at (bottom.south -| left.south) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south east] at (bottom.south -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{63}};

   % draw frame
  \draw [Blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);

\end{tikzpicture} 


\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=5mm
]
   \node [Maroon] (text) {
   \begin{tabular}{ll}
     শিশুকে \\
     ভুল শেখাবেন না&সঠিক শেখাবেন।\\
     লোভ দেখাবেন না &পুরস্কার দেবেন \\
     নিরুৎসাহিত করেবন না&উৎসাহিত করেবন\\
     বকুনি দেবেন না&উপেদশ দেবেন \\
     বেয়াদব বলেবন না&আদব শেখাবেন \\
     নিঃসঙ্গ  রাখবেন না&সৎসঙ্গ দেবেন \\
     ভয় দেখাবেন না&সাহস দেবেন \\
     লজ্জা দেবেন না& শিখিয়ে দেবেন \\
     ধমক দেবেন না&বুঝতে দেবেন \\
     মিথ্যা বলবেন না&সত্য বলবেন \\
     বেত্রাঘাত করবেন না &স্নেহ করবেন \\
     নিন্দা করেবন না&ভালবাসবেন \\
     অবেহলা করবেন না&গুরুত্ব দেবেন \\
     মাওলানা মুরশিদুল আলম & মুহতামিম\\ 
     জামিয়া আরাবিয়া হাজী ইউনুছ (কওমী মাদ্রাসা)
    \end{tabular}
    };



  \path 
    let
    \p1=(text.south west),
    \p2=(text.north east),
    \n1={\x2-\x1}, % width of text node
    \n2={\y2-\y1}  % height of text node
    in
% in all of the below some fraction of \n1 or \n2 is used to define the width of the ornaments
% set width of these ornaments to half the text node's width
   node [anchor=north] (below) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1,symmetry=c]{69}}
   node [anchor=south] (above) at (text.north) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1]{69}}
% use \n2 for ornament width here
   node [rotate=-90, left=of text, anchor=north] (left)  {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
   node [rotate=90, right=of text, anchor=north] (right) {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
% and \n1 here
   node [above=of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
   node [below=of below] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
% and 25% of width for the corner ornaments
   node [anchor=north west] at (top.north -| left.south)  {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1]{63}}
   node [anchor=north east] at (top.north -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=v]{63}}
   node [anchor=south west] at (bottom.south -| left.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=h]{63}}
   node [anchor=south east] at (bottom.south -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=c]{63}}; % <- note the \path doesn't end until here

   % draw frame
  \draw [Blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, reading Bangla for you is difficult. Actually there are some good advice from a wise man for the parents of children. I will try to give a English translated copy of this.