# How to position a node with respect to another node?

Tags: tikz-uml

[image]
[taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396436/128718 ]

I want to use something like

```
\node[basic,anchor=north.west, xshift=5cm] {instructor.south.east}(department) {department,
```

instead of

```
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor] (department) {department
```

That means x-coordinate distance between `north.west` corner of `department` and `south.east` corner of `instructor` is 5cm.

MWE(taken from @marmot)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape
    },
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape
                      }}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[basic] (instructor) {instructor
\nodepart{second}
\underline{ID}\\
name\\
salary};
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor] (department) {department
%I want to 
%\node[basic,anchor=north,yshift=-3cm] (department)(instructor.south) {department
\nodepart{second}
\underline{dept\_name}\\
building\\
budget};
\draw (instructor) -- (department) node[midway,Diamond]{member};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: I have completely misunderstood what you want. The syntax is

```
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor.south,anchor=north] (department) ...
```

Here is the MWE for that:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape
    },
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape
                      }}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[basic] (instructor) {instructor
\nodepart{second}
\underline{ID}\\
name\\
salary};
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor.south,anchor=north] (department) {department
\nodepart{second}
\underline{dept\_name}\\
building\\
budget};
\draw (instructor) -- (department) node[midway,Diamond]{member};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: I was under the impression you wanted to combine [Torbjørn's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396436/128718) with the "basic" style. That's possible, e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd} %<- added simplified here in order to avoid
% empty splits
% redefine enviroment
\renewenvironment{class}[3][]%
{
\begin{classAndInterfaceCommon}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}%
{\calcuateNumberOfParts{}
% Thorbjorns only change was in the following line, where "anchor=north" was moved before "this umlcd style"
% but I replaced "this umlcd style" by "basic=\theumlcdClassSplitPartNum"
% and changed the way you define the position. Essentially you need to put 
% brackets around
\node[anchor=north,basic=\theumlcdClassSplitPartNum] (\umlcdClassName) at \umlcdClassPos
    {\textbf{\umlcdClassName}
\insertAttributesAndOperations{}
};

\end{classAndInterfaceCommon}
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape
    },
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape
                      }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{class}{foo}{(0,0)}
\attribute{+ Public}
\end{class}

\begin{class}{bar}{([yshift=-10mm]foo.south)}
\attribute{+ balance : Dollars}
\operation{+ deposit( amount : Dollars )}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[anchor=west]{baz}{([xshift=20mm]bar.east)}
\end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code works essentially like Torbjørn's except that you now have to put all the placement information in the third argument and put parentheses around, examples are provided above. As a bonus, the nodes won't be split any more if that's not necessary. Clearly, depending on what you want to do, you may want to increase the `text width` of the nodes and so on.

Comment: No need to make complex your code. I want to use your previous solution. Just make change in giving position. I want to use something like `\node[basic,anchor=north.west, xshift=5cm] {instructor.south.east}(department) {department`, instead of `\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor] (department) {department`

Comment: see edited question.

Comment: @alhelal Does `\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor.south,anchor=north] (department) {department ...` give you what you want?

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: Then I guess you can make a solution with `xshift` and `yshift`