# UML messy diagram

Tags: tikz-uml

I have 7 classes and wanted to make a UML-diagram of these in latex. I did manage to code it but take a look at the result (I did even try to rescale and rearrange):
[image]
You can't even identify all the lines showing the relationships. The UML is very messy as you can see so I would like to know if it is possible to make this UML in Latex such that it looks more clean?
Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[schoo,simplified]{pgf-umlcd}
\date{January 2019}

\begin{document}



\maketitle

\section{UML-diagram (se næste side)}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{package}{Chess}
\begin{class}[text width = 5cm]{chessPiece}{0,0}
    \attribute{\textit{nameOfType : string}}
    \attribute{color : Color}
    \attribute{position : Position option with get/set = None}
    \attribute{\textit{candidateRelativeMoves : Position list list}}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{ToString : unit $\rightarrow$ string}
    \operation{availableMoves : Board $\rightarrow$ Position list}
    \operation{isThreatened : Board : chessPiece : Position $\rightarrow$ bool}
    \operation{}
\end{class}
\begin{class}[text width = 5cm]{Board}{-5.5,0}
    \attribute{Item : : chessPiece option with set}
    \operation{static validPositionWrap : Position $\rightarrow$ Position option}
    \operation{ToString : unit $\rightarrow$ string}
    \operation{move : Position : Position $\rightarrow$ unit}
    \operation{getVacantNOccupied : chessPiece : Position list $\rightarrow$ unit}
    \operation{getVacantNNeighbours : chessPiece : Position list $\rightarrow$ unit}
\end{class}
\end{package}
\begin{package}{Pieces}
\begin{class}[text width = 3cm]{king}{-11,-1}
\inherit{chessPiece}
\attribute{nameOfType : string= "king"}
\attribute{candidateRelativeMoves = [[(-1,0)];[(-1,1)];[(0,1)];[(1,1)];
      [(1,0)];[(1,-1)];[(0,-1)];[(-1,-1)]]}
\end{class}
\begin{class}[text width = 3cm]{rook}{-11,-5}
    \inherit{chessPiece}
    \attribute{nameOfType : string= "rook"}
    \attribute{candidateRelativeMoves = List.map (swap List.map [1..7]) indToRel}
\end{class}
\end{package}
\begin{package}{Interactives}
\begin{class}[text width = 5cm]{Player}{0,-8}
    \attribute{pieceToMove : chessPiece option = None}
    \operation{nextMove : Board $\rightarrow$ string}
\end{class}
\begin{class}[text width = 5 cm]{Human}{0, -11}
    \inherit{Player}
\end{class}
\end{package}
\begin{class}[text width = 5cm]{Game}{-8,-10}
    \attribute{player1 : Human}
    \attribute{player2 : Human}
    \attribute{\_board : Board}
    \operation{setup : unit}
    \operation{run : unit}
    \operation{valid : string [] $\rightarrow$ Human $\rightarrow$ bool}
\end{class}
\unidirectionalAssociation {chessPiece}{}{}{Board}
\unidirectionalAssociation{Game}{}{}{chessPiece}
\unidirectionalAssociation{Game}{}{}{Player}
\composition{Game}{}{}{king}
\composition{Game}{}{}{rook}
\composition{Game}{}{}{Human}
\composition{Game}{}{}{Board}
\composition{Player}{}{}{chessPiece}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Example of a way better version, with example of a modified arrow:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  In addition to providing a MWE, you should ask a specific question.  For example, do you want the pieces of the diagram to be spaced out more?  Do you want the arrowheads to be larger?  etc.  You might also want to include an image of a UML diagram (maybe from the web somewhere) that you think looks good.

Comment: @James Well, I do not care how it is done, I just want the UML to be understandable and not messy as the one I showed.

Comment: @samcarter The post has been edited with the code to compile it. Thanks for the tip :) Hope you or someone else can help now.

Comment: @npp Unfortunately your code does not compile because things like `\end{document}` are missing.

Comment: Yea okay forgot to add that :/ Edited again now.

Comment: @samcarter now it should work

Comment: @npp No, still not compiling

Comment: @samcarter It does compile for me on overleaf.. :/

Comment: @npp  Overleaf is just very good at hiding error messages. It won't compile because no title is given and package options are misspelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does this look? Mostly I just repositioned things a bit, changed some `text width`s and the font size. Note I positioned some of the classes relative to other classes (see [Is there any method to create UML using LaTeX without giving (x,y) co-ordinate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396431/is-there-any-method-to-create-uml-using-latex-without-giving-x-y-co-ordinate/396436#396436) for more about that), which makes aligning things easier.

If you have suggestions for modifications, feel free to add them in comments. For example, it would certainly be possible to draw the various arrows differently, they need not be straight lines, but it might require some more manual work, rather than `pgf-umlcd`s macro (`\composition` etc.).

The code below show a few methods for making the inherit-arrow between `king` and `chessPiece` go around the `Chess` package. This is done "manually", using a standard TikZ `\draw` macro.

They mostly make use of defining named coordinates at the corner points of the path, and using `-|`/`|-` path specifications (see [TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429)) to draw the line. To get the correct look, I add the `umlcd style inherit line` style. Some of the methods require specific TikZ libraries, mentioned in comments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[school,simplified]{pgf-umlcd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize] % reduce fontsize
\begin{package}{Chess}
\begin{class}[text width = 3.3cm]{chessPiece}{0,0}
    \attribute{\textit{nameOfType : string}}
    \attribute{color : Color}
    \attribute{position : Position option with get/set = None}
    \attribute{\textit{candidateRelativeMoves : Position list list}}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{ToString : unit $\rightarrow$ string}
    \operation{availableMoves : Board $\rightarrow$ Position list}
    \operation{isThreatened : Board : chessPiece : Position $\rightarrow$ bool}
    \operation{}
\end{class}
\begin{class}[text width = 3cm, xshift=-3cm]{Board}{chessPiece.north west}
    \attribute{Item : : chessPiece option with set}
    \operation{static validPositionWrap : Position $\rightarrow$ Position option}
    \operation{ToString : unit $\rightarrow$ string}
    \operation{move : Position : Position $\rightarrow$ unit}
    \operation{getVacantNOccupied : chessPiece : Position list $\rightarrow$ unit}
    \operation{getVacantNNeighbours : chessPiece : Position list $\rightarrow$ unit}
\end{class}
\end{package}
\begin{package}{Pieces}
\begin{class}[text width = 3.3cm, xshift=-4cm]{king}{Board.north west}
%\inherit{chessPiece}
\attribute{nameOfType : string= "king"}
\attribute{candidateRelativeMoves = [[(-1,0)];[(-1,1)];[(0,1)];[(1,1)];
      [(1,0)];[(1,-1)];[(0,-1)];[(-1,-1)]]}
\end{class}
\begin{class}[text width = 3.3cm, yshift=-5mm]{rook}{king.south}
    \inherit{chessPiece}
    \attribute{nameOfType : string= "rook"}
    \attribute{candidateRelativeMoves = List.map (swap List.map [1..7]) indToRel}
\end{class}
\end{package}
\begin{package}{Interactives}
\begin{class}[text width = 3.3cm, yshift=-2cm]{Player}{chessPiece.south}
    \attribute{pieceToMove : chessPiece option = None}
    \operation{nextMove : Board $\rightarrow$ string}
\end{class}
\begin{class}[text width = 3.3cm, yshift=-1cm]{Human}{Player.south}
    \inherit{Player}
\end{class}
\end{package}
\begin{class}[text width = 4cm, xshift=-4cm]{Game}{Player.north west}
    \attribute{player1 : Human}
    \attribute{player2 : Human}
    \attribute{\_board : Board}
    \operation{setup : unit}
    \operation{run : unit}
    \operation{valid : string [] $\rightarrow$ Human $\rightarrow$ bool}
\end{class}
\unidirectionalAssociation {chessPiece}{}{}{Board}
\unidirectionalAssociation{Game}{}{}{chessPiece}
\unidirectionalAssociation{Game}{}{}{Player}
\composition{Game}{}{}{king}
\composition{Game}{}{}{rook}
\composition{Game}{}{}{Human}
\composition{Game}{}{}{Board}
\composition{Player}{}{}{chessPiece}

%% method 1
%\path (king.east) ++(1cm,0) coordinate (m1)
%      (chessPiece.north) ++(0,1.2cm) coordinate(m2);
%\draw [umlcd style inherit line] (chessPiece.north) -- (m2) -| (m1) -- (king.east);

%% method 2 -- requires \usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\draw [umlcd style inherit line]
%     let
%         \p1=(king.east),\p2=(Board.west)
%     in
%     (chessPiece.north) -- ++(0,1.2cm) -| ($(\x1,\y1)!0.5!(\x2,\y1)$) -- (king.east);

%% method 3 -- requires \usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\draw [umlcd style inherit line] (chessPiece.north) -- ++(0,1.2cm) -| ($(king.east)+(1.2cm,0)$) -- (king.east);

%% method 4 -- requires \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\coordinate [above left=of Chess] (m3);
%\draw [umlcd style inherit line] (chessPiece) |- (m3) |- (king);

%% method 5
\coordinate (m4) at ([shift={(-4mm,7mm)}]Chess.north west);
\draw [umlcd style inherit line] (chessPiece) |- (m4) |- (king);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow beautiful! This helped so much. Regarding the arrows, could you provide an example such as by making the inheritance arrow going from `king` to `chessPiece` go above the chess package and point down to `chessPiece`? I added an illustration in my question :)

Comment: @npp I updated the answer, showing a few different variations.

Comment: Simply perfect.